# Why is sh (not bash) complaining about functions defined in my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, shell, bash-functions

I am getting this one when I open a terminal session:

> sh: error importing function definition for `read.json'
>
> sh: error importing function definition for `ts-project'

sh doesn't like these functions because they look like:

```
read.json(){
   ::
}
```

and

```
ts-project(){
   ::
}
```

the real question is - why is `sh` touching/interpreting these files? I am on MacOS and seen this before, it's such a mystery. I would think only bash would be loading these files.

*update*: bash and sh are nothing out of the ordinary.
when I type bash into the terminal, I get this:

```
alex$ bash
beginning to load .bashrc
finished loading .bashrc
bash-3.2$
```

when I type `sh` in the terminal, I get this:

```
alex$ sh
sh: error importing function definition for `read.json'
sh: error importing function definition for `ts-project'
sh-3.2$
```

Comment: Perhaps /bin/sh *is* bash on that system?

Comment: Do you have a ~/.profile file that sources either .bashrc or .bash_profile?

Comment: none of them source each other, I discovered that was a bad practice the hard way. however, ~/.profile is sourcing a shared bash file, so maybe `sh` is what sources the .profile file?

Comment: I updated the OP to address your questions

Comment: The information about having a ~/.profile file that sources the shared file seems important to me.

Comment: What I meant by /bin/sh being bash is that it's possible that it's symlinked or hardlinked to bash. Bash then emulates sh, but also sources ~/.profile. I just don't know how OSX packages sh and bash.

Comment: yeah I am investigating thanks for info

Comment: it is strange that sh and bash are both on version 3.2 exactly?

Comment: They're built from the same `bash` source, the one with `STRICT_POSIX`, the other without it.

Comment: so STRICT_POSIX makes the weird bash function names unpalatable?

Comment: [Yes](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c?id=9f597fd10993313262cab400bf3c46ffb3f6fd1e#n391). `-DSTRICT_POSIX` turns on `posixly_correct` by default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That error happens when `bash` masquerading as a POSIX shell tries to import those functions from the environment, not when loading them by interpreting a file like `~/.bashrc` or such. Simplified example:

```
foo.bar(){ true; }; export -f foo.bar; bash --posix -c true
bash: error importing function definition for `foo.bar'
```

I was expecting `bash` not to load functions from the environment when in posix mode, but [it does](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c?id=9f597fd10993313262cab400bf3c46ffb3f6fd1e#n391), and only complains when their names contain funny characters.

Notice that `bash` will also run in posix mode when the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` or `POSIX_PEDANTIC` environment variable is set, or when it was compiled with `--enable-strict-posix-default` / `STRICT_POSIX`.

This latter seems to be the case for `/bin/sh` on MacOS (look [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-106/bash.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.auto.html) for `PRODUCT_NAME = sh`), where I expect this error to also trigger when using library functions like `popen(3)` or `system(3)`.

Comment: The fix: don't export functions in the environment. It's the bash anti-feature that led to (or rather, simply was) Shellshock and it should have been removed, but wasn't because people are foolishly using it. Don't be one of them.

Comment: The fact that bash imports functions even when called as `sh` is what made the shellshock/bashdoor vulnerability a **lot** worse.

Comment: See also `SHELLOPTS=posix` and `-o posix` for other ways to enable the posix mode.

Comment: Also note that `set -a` / `set -o allexport` also causes bash to export all functions (and if invoked as `sh`, causes `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to be set and exported!)

Comment: (`sh -a` causes `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to be set and exported; `set -a` after `sh` without `-a` was started doesn't export `POSIXLY_CORRECT` because it was set before `-a` was in effect).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it seems that the functions are imported _before_ `SHELLOPTS` is processed. This will complain about `baz.quux` but not about `foo.bar`: `bash -c 'foo.bar(){ echo yup; }; export -f foo.bar; set -o posix; export SHELLOPTS; bash -c "foo.bar; baz.quux(){ :; }"'`.

Comment: Same thing when invoking a `bash` _not_ compiled with with `-DSTRICT_POSIX` as `sh` (eg. on rhel, centos where `/bin/sh` is a regular `bash`) -- functions with funny names will be imported from the environment, but no new functions like that can be defined. All this is still the case in the latest version (5.0.9).

Comment: @mosvy, yes it's all about the order things are processed, it is all a bit messy. When bash is invoked as `sh`, POSIX mode ends up being set quite late. Same with `SHELLOPTS`.

Comment: How can I check if POSIX mode is turned on with bash?

Comment: @AlexanderMills `case :$SHELLOPTS: in *:posix:*) ...`

Answer (score 5):

To answer the part about why `read.json` and `ts-project` are not portable function names:

According to POSIX, a [function definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05) must be [named](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) by

> a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a name is not a digit.

Also known as an *identifier*, in C lingo. Or in regex: `[_a-zA-Z][0-9_a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: But POSIX doesn't forbid implementations from accepting other names for functions, so bash didn't *have* to impose those restrictions when in POSIX mode. function names share the same namespace as command arguments, so there's no reason to accept just _anything_ (like `zsh`/`rc`/`fish`...)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I know, but what does it mean to be in POSIX mode, if not "shed all extensions", as in "not silently accept them"?

Comment: @user2394284 it certainly doesn't mean that in `bash`, or it would not import functions from the environment while in POSIX mode, which is not required by the POSIX spec ;-)

Comment: @mosvy: Yeah, it's evident that bash failed somewhere along the way – I would say at being a plain POSIX shell, which would be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

So what caused it was I am sourcing some bash scripts in my ~/.bashrc file like so:

```
for f in "$HOME/.oresoftware/bash/"*; do
   . "$f"
done;
```

so I just changed it to:

```
for f in "$HOME/.oresoftware/bash/"*; do
  if [[ "$(basename "$0")" != 'sh' ]]; then
      # source only if not using sh
      . "$f"
  fi
done;
```

so in theory if it's called by `sh` then it won't try to source those files, but not sure if this work 100% of the time.